# цикл по обратному ходу в слау

Tags: c++, матрицы

Прошу помочь составить цикл по обратному ходу в методе гаусса(в слау),например 4 на 5 ,и если знаете как , то улучшить. Желательно не при помощи вектор столбцов и тд, т.к я еще начинающий,
например как то так :
Или подскажите идею как можно это сделать компактнее и легче
P.S R для обратной матрицы

```
  cout << "Pryamoi hod" << endl;
    for (int d = 0; d < size - 1; d++)//прямой ход
    {
        for (int i = d + 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            double tmp = double(A[i][d] / A[d][d]);
            for (int j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[d][j] * tmp;
                R[i][j] = R[i][j] - R[d][j] * tmp;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример обратного хода:

```
for (int d = size - 1; d >= 0; --d)
{
    double tmp = A[d][size];
    for (int j = d + 1; j < size; j++)
    {
        tmp -= A[d][j] * A[j][j];
    }
    A[d][d] = tmp / A[d][d];
}
```

По итогу мы получаем матрицу A в которой элементы по диагонали являются значениями x(i).

Я не стал писать комментарии, надеюсь и без них все понятно, но если появятся вопросы, то не стесняйтесь задавать их.

Comment: У меня по какой то причине не работает ваш цикл

Comment: еще такой момент , элемента A[4][4](в цикле A[j][j]) просто нету в матрице

Comment: если взять матрицу 4 на 5 например

Comment: то  , там строки от 0 до 3 , столбцы от 0 до 4

Comment: ваш цикл только изменил элементы на главной диагонали и все , в матрице сверху должны появится нули и должен изменится 5 столбец

Comment: под сверху я имею ввиду выше главной диагонали

Comment: 1) Не знаю почему не работает. 2) Ну так и у меня не существует такого элемента. `size = 4` и вложенный цикл `j < size` будет идти от [0, 3]. 3) Насчет нулей не знал, но это легко добавить. Просто во вложенном цикле после строчки `tmp -= A[d][j] * A[j][j]` напишите `A[d][j] = 0` 4) 5 столбец изменяется и так

Comment: идея в том чтобы не просто занулить элемент а сделать алгебраические преобразования (например сложить строку со строчкой)